# How can i change the default name for the screenshots made by gnome-screenshot?

Tags: gnome, screenshot

Gnome-screenshot 3.1.2 uses filenames like this one

> Screenshot at 2011-07-31 12:13:04.png

making it rather easy to see when it was taken.

The problem is that it uses the colon ( : ) character - making it impossible to access such an image from Windows.

Considering I take most of my screenshots so I can send them to Windows users this has caused some problems.

Is there any way to change the default name that is used by the screenshot tool to replace the ":" with "." or "," ?

Answer (score 18):

It is not actually possible change it easily, maybe you can help with this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684662).

(for the curious, check the [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-screenshot/tree/src/screenshot-filename-builder.c). Currently, relevant line is [134](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-screenshot/tree/src/screenshot-filename-builder.c#n134))

**Update**: The [bug was fixed upstream on 2015-01-28](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740520), replacing colons with dashes, which helps.  But they didn't take the space out unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for linking to source code. Now THAT is the linux way. (Although the file name code is actually here, now: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-utils/tree/gnome-screenshot/screenshot-filename-builder.c)

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead: **No repositories found**

Comment: New URL: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-screenshot/tree/src/screenshot-filename-builder.c#n134 (retrieved at 2013-02-16 18:08 UTC+0800)

Comment: I wish we could tweak this locally before good old GNOME developers wake up a little quicker to such important problems reported by users ;-)

Comment: Whoever thought it a good idea to hardcode screenshot names in C, requiring a recompile of the _entire_ desktop environment? Had no one ever thought that a user might want to change the default naming? Now that there is `dconf-editor` and such, and `gnome-screenshot` uses it, why not have a dconf entry stting for "screenshot naming policy" which you could set to say `Screenshot-%02d.png`, and if empty, then go along with the hardcoded naming policy? Eh....

Answer (score 11):

`gnome-screenshot` doesn't allow setting a global default for the screenshot filenames, but you can use the `-f` option to specify a filename on the commandline.

We can use that to write a small bash script that will take the place of the original `gnome-screenshot` binary and will execute the original with the correct filename parameter.

Note that you will have to have root privileges for the following operations, so prefix each command with `sudo` or open a root shell with `sudo -i`.

1. Move the original `gnome-screenshot` binary out of the way:

   ```bash
   dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.real /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
   ```
2. Open `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot` in an editor (you should see a new empty file):

   ```bash
   editor /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
   ```
3. Paste the following two lines into the editor:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash  
   gnome-screenshot.real -f "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots/$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S).png" $@
   ```

   You can insert any path you like after the `-f`; just make sure to enclose it in quotation marks and to keep the `$@` after it.
   In this example, the screenshots will be stored with filenames like `/home/yourusername/Pictures/Screenshots/2011-07-31_12-13-04.png`. See `man date` for details on the `date +%…` syntax.
4. Save the file and close the editor (e.g. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> in Nano or `:wq` in Vim).
5. Make the newly created script executable:

   ```bash
   chmod a+x /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
   ```

Comment: This works great. How would I make it so that the file name is prepended with the letters "SS" ?

Comment: @user147176 You can change the filename template in step 3, e.g. add "SS" before the `$(…)` that produces the date/time string.

Comment: Replacing a file managed by package management is a bad idea: a package update will replace your replacement with the original. So put the wrapper into `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin` instead, and make sure that directory is in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @ReinierPost Using `dpkg-divert` (step 1) ensures that the package manager is aware of the new location of the package-provided file, and will update that instead of our replacement version.

Comment: @n.st Sure, but I would recommend against it.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple and dirty way to rename all the screenshot taken immediately after the creation, but you will need to install inotify-tools  ( `apt-get install inotify-tools` ) and then you could run this command:

```
while true; do inotifywait -e CREATE ~/Pictures && rename 's/\:/\./g' Pictures/Screenshot*.png; done;
```

While this command will run, every time you save a new screenshot in Pictures/, the script will rename every file containing `:`, substituting `:` with `.`

(Maybe you want change the directory, I don't know which directory Gnome 3 uses)
If you really like it, you can start this command in a script every time gnome starts.

Comment: +1 This is a neat little trick, but your regex should be 's/\:/\./g'

Comment: another option of replacement: use the unicode character `：`

Comment: Note that screenshots are saved by default in `~/Pictures`, not `~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of installing additional software and writing this code in the screenshot tool, here's a workaround to rename the files afterwards.

All you need to do is to navigate to the directory and run the following command

```
rename 's/\:/\-/g' *.png
```

This will replace all colons with dashes in all file names ending in `.png` of the ones present in the current directory.

Comment: Less optimal, but much easier workaround than [proposed by fain182](http://askubuntu.com/a/55235/88802). +1

Comment: Btw, I'd consider putting this in a cron executed every minute.  Well, I'll opt for n.st's solution instead, but this approach is, at least, very simple.

Answer (score 5):

[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) is another application for taking screenshots which allows you to customize the file name: you can install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Shutter is amazing by itself, and this is imho this is the best approach: instead of *fixing* bad filenames, do not produce them!

Comment: For example, the filename in the Shutter may have the following wildcard: `$nb_name_%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`. You can set  it in the Preferences.

Comment: I love Shutter but for quick screenshots that don't need annotation, I still prefer to use the default Ubuntu Screenshot program because it instantly gives two options - Copy to Clipboard or Save as. Fast and easy.

Comment: @VladimirS. Where did you find those format string values?  I found *this* page searching for documentation on this.

Comment: @Michael You can find it [here](https://shutter-project.org/wp-content/uploads/screenshot_017.png) (at least some of them)

Answer (score 1):

If:

1. you are familiar with binary editing tools such as `bless`(see [ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bless) for example or [github](https://github.com/bwrsandman/Bless)),
2. and you know C string format modifiers,
3. and you know the difference between `0x0` and `"0"`,
4. and you do not mind messing around with binary files installed by your Linux distribution of choice,

then you can modify the file name that is used by `gnome-screenshot`.

When binary editing `gnome-screenshot`, you will find two format strings:

1. `%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S` followed by a null byte,
2. and `Screenshot from %s.%s` followed by a null byte.

In the second format string, the first `%s` is the date, the second `%s` is the file extension.

From here, you can, for example, **overwrite** `%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S` with `%F-%H%M%S` followed by a null byte and `Screenshot from %s.%s` by `shot %s.%s` followed by a null byte: screenshots will then be named `"shot 2018-05-05_174857.png"` for example.

Adapt to your preferences.

There are two constraints:

1. the new date format and the new file name format must not be longer than the original ones,
2. your customizations will be destroyed if you install a new version of `gnome-screenshot`, for example when updating your system.

Warnings:

- Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, your mileage may vary.
- This is a **hack**, not a clean way of modifying the default name generated by `gnome-screenshot`: make a **backup** before proceeding.
- Posted without any warranty of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian 8.6 KDE → System settings → Custom shortcuts, I have set Trigger → PrtScn, and Action →

```
gnome-screenshot -p -f "$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)_D.png"
```

and it works fine.

Comment: I wonder which Debian-version has been recent five years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine.  I expanded on n.st's answer.

Create a shell script to call `gnome-screenshot`

Save this to the file: `/usr/bin/area_screenshot`

You may need to use `sudo`.  So use `vi` to create it. 
`sudo vi /usr/bin/area_screenshot`

Copy the code below into it.

```
#!/bin/bash

screenshot_dir="$HOME/Documents/screenshot"
current_year_dir="$screenshot_dir/$(date +%Y)"
current_month_dir="$current_year_dir/$(date +%Y_%m)"
fileout="$current_month_dir/$(date +%Y_%m%d_%H%M%S).png"

# Step 1: Check for screenshot directory 
[ -d "$screenshot_dir" ] || mkdir "$screenshot_dir"

# Step 2: Check year and month directory
[ -d "$current_year_dir" ] || mkdir "$current_year_dir"
[ -d "$current_month_dir" ] || mkdir "$current_month_dir"

# Step 3: Take area screenshot, and save to the current month 
[ -d "$current_month_dir" ] && /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot -a -f "$fileout" $@
```

Then, mark the file as executable. 
`chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/area_screenshot`

Then, in your keyboard shortcuts, set `area_screenshot` to the `Printscreen` button.  You will need to create a custom shortcut for this (maybe someone else can link an example to do this).

**What does this do?**

It will create a screenshot at `HOME/Documents/YEAR/YEAR_MONTH/filex.png`.

Where `filex.png` is in the format `YYYY_MMDD_HHMMSS.png`.  So for example, `2019_1220_121314.png`.

**How is this helpful?**
I find this technique is quite useful to take screenshots of comments and articles.  Over time, I capture a lot, so it's very convenient to get it automatically categorized into subfolders.  Then over the years, they keep accumulating, and the `year` subfolder keeps it nicely organized.  I tend to put the current month in my favorites link (in Windows), and manually update it every month, as I usually only need to look at the current month.

It would be great if Ubuntu, Fedora, etc., made something like this as the standard on Linux.  Please take my code example, and make it so!  It would help everyone by keeping their screenshots nicely organized.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55204/how-can-i-change-the-default-name-for-the-screenshots-made-by-gnome-screenshot/836535#836535) that applies to Debian, this pertains to Ubuntu 20.04 "Focal Fossa":

I set a custom keyboard shortcut to be:

```
gnome-screenshot [--flags] --file=file:///home/User/Pictures/Screenshots/$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S).jpg
```

*(If you are copying this, replace `User` with your own username.)*

`--flags` could be any of the options. You can learn more about `gnome-screenshot` from [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/taking-screenshots-in-linux-using-gnome-screenshot/).

I set the shortcut to be triggered with the <kbd>PRINT SCR</kbd> button and it works like a charm for me now.