# Screenshot without hiding context menus?

Tags: firefox, interface, screenshot

I know, the pre-installed screenshot applications usually have a screenshot countdown feature. But how can I take immediate screenshots of context menus?

This includes:

- Firefox main menu.
- Firefox download menu.
- Right click context menu on taskbar tray items.
- Collapsed File-Edit-View menus.
- Right-click menu for files in file manager.

When pressing the print key, these context menus hide immediately before the screen is grabbed. How can I make the context menus stay while pressing the print (screenshot) key?

Comment: Not sure whether it's (*easily*) doable *without using the countdown timer feature*.

Comment: So you **don't** want the area surrounding the context menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I take screenshots with a delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252281/how-do-i-take-screenshots-with-a-delay)

Comment: But @WinEunuuchs2Unix it seems OP is aware of that, but doesn't want to use it: "*But how can I take **immediate** screenshots of context menus?*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @pomsky sorry it's late after all day research. I'll retract my close vote. thanks :)

Comment: @DKBose Yes, I wish to capture the whole screen immediately but without the context menu hiding.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you for retracting your closevote.

Comment: I've tried several of the common screen capture tools and haven't come across any that can do what you want.