# screenshot with a delay

Tags: screenshot

Release: "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS", XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11

Hello, I often take screenshots and usually the built in screenshot taker is fine - the one you get when you hit the PrtScn key.

But sometimes, I want to make use of a delay - I need to take a screenshot with my mouse hovering on something so for example a tooltip pops up. I used to use kazam for that, but this now only takes transparent pngs :/

Any good screenshot utilities I should take a look at?

Comment: Please edit your question to point us toward a step-by-step example. When I try capturing an image of a tooltip+mouse in this page rendered in FireFox, it works properly.

Comment: I ah can't take a screenshot of the screenshot tool not giving me an option to delay the capturing of the screenshot because AFAIK the screenshot capturing tool can't take a screenshot of itself

Comment: You don't need to take a screenshot of the screenshot tool. That would be silly. Simply edit your question to explain a step-by-step example of how to reproduce the problem. Be specific about an application or website so we can reproduce it *exactly*. If we cannot reproduce it, we cannot help you much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I take screenshots with a delay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252281/how-do-i-take-screenshots-with-a-delay)

Comment: Look mate there is only one step - hit PrtScn - and I've been specific about the application.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the smoothest solution, but in lieu of picking a specific tool for this type of task, I've tried recording a video of the screen and using that instead (taking a screenshot of the video at the time I want) - very much a hacky workaround, but the helpful thing on my end was that I didn't have to figure out the right number of seconds to plan for in the delay - I could just do whatever it was I needed to show, stop the recording and find the specific shot I needed.

I mention that only because the GNOME screenshot utility does have a screen recording feature built-in, so that could be an option?

If you're open to the KDE/Qt-based side of things, I use Kubuntu as my daily OS now and I really love the included screenshot utility, labeled 'ksnip' in the software store, which is available as an Ubuntu distribution package, Snap, or Flatpak.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah this is how I solved the issue. Not the smoothest way but definitely flexible :)

Answer (score 0):

Screen shots can be taken using the `gnome-screenshot` command, which by default puts your whole screen's image into your `~/Pictures` directory.

For a 10 second delayed screen shot you can use something like:

```
gnome-screenshot -p -d 10
```

For more information see [man gnome-screenshot](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/gnome-screenshot.1.html).

Note: There seems to be a bug with the `-p` option and the mouse pointer is not included in the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The command-line tool `scrot` is very versatile and can do this.

`sudo apt install scrot`

<kbd>ALT+F2</kbd> `scrot -d 5` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This will wait 5 seconds then take a screenshot. Scrot is very flexible, and can be controlled to take multiple shots, only an area of the display, or separate displays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go!