# Application to turn screenshot (Ctrl+Shift+PrtScn) into file

Tags: screenshot, attachment

I want to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> - creates a partial screenshot - and save it automatically to file (to attach to email, etc...) ... Without installing a large application such as shutter or so.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Nicolaas, if my answer helped you, please mark it. Otherwise, please comment what you think is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>print</kbd> should save it in a file in your `~/Picture` folder.

Keys are here (System Setting -> Keyboard):

[image: System Setting -> Keyboard]

Notice that there is a little problem I have found a couple of time. The saved file is named something like `Screenshot 2013-11-04 10:00:03.png`. If you copy that file to a Dropbox folder (for example) or other shared folder with a Windows machine, it will not appear on the Windows side, because the colon `:` is a forbidden char in Windows filenames. So you have to rename it... for more deatils see: [How can i change the default name for the screenshots made by gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55204/how-can-i-change-the-default-name-for-the-screenshots-made-by-gnome-screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Simply press printscr. I do it all the time on accident b/c it's right beside my backspace and delete keys :( it prompts you to save a picture of your desktop.