# How do I modify filenames in a folder using a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Whenever I download .docx and .ppt files from my school, they always look like this.

> UTF-8"File%20Name%20Example.docx

It's pretty annoying to have to rename the file every time I download one, so I want to create a bash script that will do the work for me.

I have a School folder, so I'd like to do a bash script that searches the entire directory and subdirectories for any files that start with the "UTF-8"" prefix, then.

- Have a for loop that removes the prefix from all files starting with that prefix
- Search the filename for occurences of "%20" and replace it with " "
- Monitor the School folder so that any time I download another file with the prefix, it will run the script and immediately rename it.

I am pretty new to linux. I have been researching for the last two hours and I am confused on what I should do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `inotifywait` and `rename` like described here [How can i change the default name for the screenshots made by gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/a/55235/178692). A suitable regular expression for the `rename` portion might be `'s/^UTF-8"//;s/%20/ /g'` .

Answer (score 2):

A basic example of how to monitor files in a folder with systemd.path (in this case /opt/download).

/etc/systemd/system/download-monitor.path:

```
[Unit]
Description=Download Monitor

[Path]
PathExistsGlob=/opt/download/UTF8\"*

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next, we need to create a .service file with the same basename as the .path file.

/etc/systemd/system/download-monitor.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Download Monitor

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/filecheck.sh
```

Last the Exec script file.

/opt/bin/filecheck.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

# systemd.path does not pass what changed so we
# rename all .docx and .ppt files starting with
# UTF8\" in the $a folder.
a=/opt/download
for b in $a/UTF8\"*@(.docx|.ppt); do
    c="$a/${b#$a/UTF8\"}"
    mv "$b" "$c" && deurlname "$c"
done
```

<sup>The **deurlname** command is found in the renameutils package.</sup>

Now we can enable and start our path monitor:

```
$ systemctl enable download-monitor.path
$ systemctl start  download-monitor.path
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[incron](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/)** for this purpose. It is like a cron, but uses events as triggers.

```
sudo apt install incron
sudo systemctl enable incron
```

Add your current user to `/etc/incron.allow` file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/incron.allow 
[sudo] password for myuser: 
myuser
```

After you've added your user to that file, you could edit `incrontab` file by that user:

```
incrontab -e
/home/myuser/test/utfnames      IN_CREATE       /home/myuser/test/renamefiles.sh
```

As you can see, the first column contains directory path, the second contains watched event (file creation), the third contains command or path to script.

The script contains the next:

```
for file in /home/myuser/test/utfnames/*
  do mv $file "$(echo $file | sed 's/UTF-8//' | sed 's/%20/ /g')"
done
```

Do not forget to `chmod +x /home/myuser/test/renamefiles.sh`

Testing:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ touch 'test/utfnames/UTF-8"Some%20File%20Name.docx'
myuser@ubuntu:~$ touch 'test/utfnames/UTF-8"Some%20File%20Name%202.docx'
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl start incron.service 
myuser@ubuntu:~$ ls test/utfnames/
'UTF-8"Some%20File%20Name%202.docx'  'UTF-8"Some%20File%20Name.docx'
myuser@ubuntu:~$ touch 'test/utfnames/UTF-8"Some%20File%20Name%203.docx'
myuser@ubuntu:~$ ls test/utfnames/
'"Some File Name 2.docx'  '"Some File Name 3.docx'  '"Some File Name.docx'
```