# Any chance Ubuntu could introduce a option where you can rename a screen shot before the screen shot is saved? Not sure when I can submit this feature

Tags: screenshot

Its such a drag in trawling through your screen shots to find what you want, a better way would be to take the screen shot and just before you save the screen shot there is a option where the screenshot can be saved before its saved.
I have done a search and would like to suggest this idea to the Ubuntu dev team.
I dont hink it would be that hard to implement.

Comment: There are many screenshot tools out there, so which one do you use?

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/55204/how-can-i-change-the-default-name-for-the-screenshots-made-by-gnome-screenshot] How can i change the default name for the screenshots made by gnome-screenshot?

Comment: Try flameshot. It is a very feature rich screenshot tool.

Comment: There are a number of screenshot tools, and at least one already does what you say you want (*I always opt to provide file-name when I make screenshots too; by default my tool shows me the screenshot & only saves it if I select to allowing me to provide name based on prior name or use SAVE AS to have a new name*)

Comment: Screenshot is actually not strictly an Ubuntu feature, but a GNOME feature in general, so feature request (if any) should be sent to GNOME developers. But I doubt they will do it, as they purposefully changed the behavior of that feature. Previously, after taking a screenshot, it popped up a dialog window asking what do you want to do with it. Now it just saves the screenshot without asking anything - so I doubt they will restore the old behavior. Apparently you can replace GNOME screenshot utility with MATE screenshot utility, which still behaves the old way, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thank you so much for these alternative options.